# can Emacs24 be installed under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, emacs

I have a new machine with a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04. For java development I use the **emacs/jdee** environment. After a fairly rigorous search, the latest emacs version that works with jdee is **emacs24**. In fact, my older machine (ubuntu 15.04) is running emacs24/jdee.  So, I can't use the emacs that pairs with ubuntu 20.04 which I believe is emacs26 or emacs27.

I've also searched around for a recipe to install emacs24 under ubuntu 20.04 and have not found anything that inspires confidence. Can it be done? Or am I in for a lot of trouble trying? If it can be done, I would very much appreciate the recipe for success. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. Turns out one can use emacs26 or emacs27, although my own experience is with emacs26. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
```

which installed emacs 26.3 build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14

As for the JDEE environment, I followed the doc provided here, which is to use MELPA and emacs own package manager : https://github.com/jdee-emacs/jdee

search on that page for 'Installing with the Emacs package system' and follow the instructions. Note I did not install JDEE-Server, only JDEE.